# new KeyWord c++ (Assistance Required)

Tags: pointers, c++11, struct, new-operator

1. I have following code that work 100 percent fine. I am also aware, what is actually going behind the scene. how "new" works in that case.

   ```
   struct ABC{
       int data = 1234;
   };
   ABC *obj = new ABC;
   cout << "obj->data";
   ```
2. The following code does not work it compiles correctly then crashed. no syntax or compile error.

   ```
   struct ABC{
       int data = 1234;
   };
   ABC *obj; // please explain??
   cout << "obj->data";
   ```
3. Following code also works fine and simple one.

   ```
   struct ABC{
       int data = 1234;
   };
   ABC *obj, myobj;
   myObj = &obj;
   cout << "obj->data";
   ```

I am also aware, hows 3<sup>rd</sup> one is working. Please explain, why 2<sup>nd</sup> one is not working. Sorry for not making main() procedure.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, printing string works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure, that lines "cout << "obj->data"" are written with " around obj->data? In your code all 3 examples must just print a same string with text="obj->data" and nothing more

Comment: If there are no quotes, the crash in 2 is easily explainable, because obj points to uninitialized memory, and dereferencing it is undefined behavior, most often observed as crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1st example you allocate a memory for a structure and initialize this structure by calling "new". And obj will contain an address to the beginning of that structure memory.

In 2nd example the variable **obj** is a pointer and it is not initialized. So it points to a random memory address.

When you are trying to read a value from this memory address (located at address stored in **obj**), two things may happen:

1. If obj points to memory block, which was assigned by OS to your program, you will receive some value, which lives at this address.
2. If obj points to some other memory block, than OS will find it out and will close your application.

In program, which is build in Debug configuration, the uninitialized variables are inited by zero by default. So your **obj** will point to address 0, reading from which is recognized by OS as error. In Release configuration all uninitialized variabled are not forced to become zeros - every value may be there.